# Which Talmud is supreme

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

How could there be two different Talmuds (Babylonian and Jerusalem) if they are both stemming from a direct oral tradition from Sinai?

Thank you

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/talmud-yerushalmi-halachot https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13058/yerushalmi-versus-bavli-in-halacha

Comment: @rosends I didn't see anything that addresses how they could be different if both claim they were transmitted orally since Sinai.

Comment: I don’t think people claim the Gemara is from Sinai, just the Mishna as the Oral Tradition. The Gemara is a commentary/discussion on the Mishna

Comment: @charlesS yes, that's why I put them in as related. They give supplemental or related information about the topic of your question.

Comment: 2 different schools of scholars interpreted the mishna and the record of their discussions form the 2 Talmuds. You might find this useful as well: [Why is Talmud Bavli studied more than Yerushalmi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92747/11501)

Comment: Have you ever heard of a "machloket"? If so is this different in some way?

Comment: Look into the history of how the Talmud came about and it is not too perplexing

Answer (score 1):

In your question `How could there be two different Talmuds (Babylonian and Jerusalem) if they are both stemming from a direct oral tradition from Sinai?` you seem to assume that the 2 Talmuds create 2 distinct sets of conclusions.

Actually, I'm not sure what you're asking - it seems you are lacking some fundamental information about the topic at hand. Here's some of that information:

The 2 Talmuds are very similar in their conclusions, on most issues. When they differ, Poskim (codifiers) will usually take both opinions into account before making a decision.

The main glaring difference is the Jerusalem Talmud being terser and records less *back & forth*.

I would venture to say that there are more *internal* arguments in the Babylonian Talmud than there are arguments between the 2 Talmuds.

They both stem from discussions on the Mishna. The Mishna is based on a *direct oral tradition from Sinai* that unfortunately got corrupted during the destruction of the 2nd temple, resulting in multiple opinions on many topics, which are the topic of most discussions in both Talmuds.

---

<sup>This answer is based on having reviewed Tractate Chagiga 100 times in the Babylonian Talmud and 30 times in the Jerusalem Talmud.</sup>

Comment: Out of curiosity why the disproportionate amount of study of tractate Chagiga?

Comment: @MordechaibenYosef - for my 50th birthday I wanted to learn at least one tractate 101 times. I chose Chagiga because you can finish it monthly @ 1-daf/day. (Then I discovered that the 101-times concept is mentioned in Chagiga.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann If you only discovered the 101-concept afterward, what was your initial reason for the seeming arbitrary number? Out of curiosity...

Comment: @Oliver I think Danny knew the concept existed but didn't know it was mentioned in Chagiga

Comment: @Oliver - as mblock said, the concept is well known, but I wasn't aware of the source.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Respect. That’s a big undertaking for something you don’t even know the origin of.